# IF statement issue in IOS using NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

My if statement won't work. `active` returns 1 but will not work in the `IF statement`

```
JSONDecoder *jsonKitDecoder = [JSONDecoder decoder];
NSDictionary *dict  = [jsonKitDecoder objectWithData:jsonData]; 

NSString *userid = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"users.user_id"];
NSString *active = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"users.active"];

NSLog(@"%@",userid);    // 2013-06-20 03:03:21.864 test[81783:c07] (74)
NSLog(@"%@",active);    // 2013-06-20 03:03:21.864 test[81783:c07] (1)

if ([active isEqualToString:@"1"]){
    // Do something
}
```

I can't seem to get this `IF` to work. Do I need to change the `NSString` to a `int`?

Comment: A way to finesse this is to use `intValue` on the extracted value.  `intValue` (or `boolValue`, `floatValue`, et al, as appropriate) is valid on both NSString and NSNumber objects, so it doesn't matter which you retrieve from the JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, use a modern style for retrieving values from dictionaries, rather than `valueForKeyPath:`.

```
NSDictionary* users = dict[@"users"];
id active = users[@"active"];
```

Once you're using a modern style, my guess is that the active value is actually an NSNumber representing a boolean value. So your if block would read:

```
if([active isKindOfClass:NSNumber] && [active boolValue]) {
    //active is an NSNumber, and the user is active
}
```

Comment: well since you're more thorough than me, +1 to you

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic, it's just obvious that the question asker needs incredibly basic, absolutely correct answers.

Comment: Thanks so much for this guys!! Still a novice.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of your if statement is just fine. I would try the alternate method for retrieving values from a dictionary as mentioned above.

`NSString *active = @"1";`

```
if ([active isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    // Do something
    NSLog(@"It works!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More than likely the "`users.active`" object being returned from that NSDictionary-ized JSON stream is a "`BOOL`" or a "`NSInteger`" as the payload of a NSNumber object and it's ***not*** a NSString object.

Try using:

```
NSNumber * activeNumber = [dict valueForKeyPath: @"users.active"];
```

and see if "`if ([activeNumber boolValue] == YES)`" works better for you.

Comment: This is not correct. `BOOL` and `NSInteger` are both primitives. You can't store primitives in an `NSDictionary`; they must be boxed in an NSObject.

Comment: Syntax is still wrong. You can't stack-initialize an `NSNumber`. Also the return type of `valueForKeyPath:` is `id`.

Comment: @michael Thanks for that. active will return 0 or 1 from a mysql db. my array looks like this  `code` Array: {
    users =     (
                {
            active = 1;
            fname = ITP;
            "user_id" = 1;
        }
    );
}
`code`

Comment: you're welcome @Snake; Idles is working hard to get the "`accept`" vote here, so I'll defer to him/her.